# How add the @CompileStatic annotation to package scope in groovy

Tags: groovy, package, typechecking, java-annotations

I would like to enforce static linking for a whole package in groovy. Static linking requires [use of CompileStatic](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/CompileStatic.html). I would like to avoid restating this on every class. How can I apply this as a package-level annotation. I have found no reference to package-level annotations in groovy.

Can you please provide a piece of code that shows how to apply the annotation to a package `a.b.c`?

Comment: Have you read any where that the mentioned annotation can be applied to package? Hence the question posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but I think it should be possible to create a nice combination of a [configurationScript](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2016/01/groovy-goodness-customising-groovy.html), a Source aware customizer and a AST transformation customizer explained in [dsl](http://groovy-lang.org/dsls.html) docs.

something like:

```
withConfig(configuration) {
    source(unitValidator: { unit -> unit.AST.classes.any { it.packageName== 'a.b.c' } }) {
        ast(CompileStatic) 
    }
}
```

Comment: haha, tested it and it worked! :)
Of course, use packageName.startsWith('a.b.c') to include subpackages.