# How to check classes have @CompileStatic annotation?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, static-analysis, structural-search, codenarc

I want to perform an automated static check analysis on my Groovy code to identify which clases doesn't have the `@CompileStatic` annotation.

I'd like to know how that can be done either with IntelliJ or CodeNarc custom rule.

Comment: After a bit of research, there's this compiler configuration that can add `@CompileStatic` at compile time https://stackoverflow.com/a/46241654/1195507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use IntelliJ IDEA's Structural Search (Edit | Find | Search Structurally...) and its Structural Search Inspection for this purpose. Use a simple pattern like this:

```
class $X$ {}
```

File type `Groovy`, Context `File`. And add a Script Constraint like the following (click on `Edit Variables...` to add constraints):

```
com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil.findAnnotation(X.parent, "groovy.transform.CompileStatic") == null
```

This should find all classes that do not have a `@CompileStatic` annotation

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, Codenarc has a [CompileStatic Rule](https://codenarc.github.io/CodeNarc/codenarc-rules-convention.html) since 1.4

> **CompileStatic Rule**
>
> Since CodeNarc 1.4
>
> Enforces classes are annotated either with one of the @CompileStatic, >@GrailsCompileStatic or @CompileDynamic annotations.